# How to see working evosuite plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, evosuite

I installed plugin in eclipse(I see it in Window -> Preferences). Still I am not able to watch quicktime video (http://www.evosuite.org/documentation/eclipse-plugin/ (due to error -2000 in windows). But main issue: I could not find in eclipse Evosuite options (I check in places mention in other anwsers).

I use eclipse Mars(4.5.2 regularly updated).

Answer (score 0):

I found that evosuite has to be added into Build path. Strange that plugin do not make it by default. Still with this all manu's are now visible.